# How to specify the updater directory from a Java application?

Tags: install4j

I'm trying to use the updater without version check to shut down the calling launcher. I've included the following in my code to launch the updater:

```
ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication("368", null, false, null);
```

I'm getting an error when it's executing this line that it can't find the `i4jparams.conf` file. It is obviously looking for the file in the same directory as the launcher, but the file is actually in the .install4j (default) subdirectory. The updater application is also in this directory.

It was working when I called the updater directly:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(".\\.install4j\\updater.exe").start();
```

Unfortunately this approach does not allow the updater to shut down the calling launcher when it is busy installing a new application.

I obviously need to tell `ApplicationLauncher.launchApplication` to look for the updater in the `.launch4j` directory, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is obviously looking for the file in the same directory as the launcher`

No, that is not the case. The actual mechanism is that is uses the directory where the JAR file with the runtime classes is located. If you put `i4jruntime.jar` into the classpath yourself, then it may use a wrong directory.

Comment: Thanks, your answer pointed me in the right direction. I had to exclude the install4j-runtime-6.1.5.jar file from the exported Maven library directory. I changed the file distribution tree definition in Install4j to exclude that specific JAR file. After that change, it's working fine now.

Comment: @Keplerian , how did you put it to work? Have a working example? If I remove the runtime file then it shows ClassNotFoundError

Comment: If you launch your application from the IDE, then you have to add i4jruntime.jar to the class path. When you build an installer, then you must not add i4jruntime,jar to the class path.

Comment: @Marckaraujo, I did not remove it from my IDE. I added the following exclusion to my library export directory in my install4j configuration file: <dirEntry file="./export_lib" ...>
        <exclude>
          <entry location="install4j-runtime-6.1.5.jar" fileType="regular" />
        </exclude>
      </dirEntry>

Comment: @Marckaraujo, I posted another answer to show how I did it from the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude the Install4j runtime library from the GUI, here is how I did it:
[image]